# Let $\ell$ be the line parametrized as $(t, 2t+1, 3t+2)$ and let $P$ be the plane with equation $x+y+z = 1$

Tags: matrices

Let $\ell$ be the line parametrized as $(t, 2t+1, 3t+2)$ and let $P$ be the plane with equation
$x+y+z = 1.$

(a) Prove that the matrix
$$\mathbf{A} =  \begin{pmatrix} -2 & -2 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 0& -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$maps all points on line $\ell$ to points on plane $P$.

(b) Prove that the matrix
$$\mathbf{B} =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 3 & 3 & -1 \\ 5& 5 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$maps all points on plane $P$ to points on line $\ell$.

I've figured out part A but need help with part B. I know this question has been asked before at [Let $\ell$ be the line parametrized as $(t, 2t+1, 3t+2)$ and let $P$ be the plane with equation $x+y+z = 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3665300/let-ell-be-the-line-parametrized-as-t-2t1-3t2-and-let-p-be-the-plan), but I have a few questions about the answer there.

1. Why must we multiply matrix B by $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1-x-y \end{pmatrix}$?
2. Assuming we do multiply matrix B and $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1-x-y \end{pmatrix}$, the result we get is $\begin{pmatrix} 2x + 2y - 1 \\ 4x+4y - 1 \\ 6x+6y-1 \end{pmatrix}.$ I don't think that lies on $(t, 2t+1, 3t+2)$....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can describe a point on a plane by two independent coordinates. They choose those coordinates to be $x$ and $y$. Note that $z$ in this case is tied to the first two by the equation of the plane. So a point $R(x,y)$ in this plane is described by $$R(x,y)=(x,y,1-x-y)$$
Now all you need to do is transform this point using the $B$ matrix to a point on the line.

For your second question, just choose $$t=2x+2y-1$$Then $$4x+4y-1=2(2x+2y-1)+1=2t+1$$
Similarly, you can get the last coordinate. Note that an entire line in the plane is mapped to the same point on the line.

Comment: Thank you very much!